# Jquery Highcharts Legend items sorting

Tags: sorting, highcharts, legend

In my application I have used jQuery Highcharts for reports.

In Highcharts, how can I sort the legend items? Means when I click on legend items, it should sort active items on top and hide items at the bottom automatically. Because I have more than 50 legend items in list. plugin has provided the pagination also. but if I active the bottom portion of the items, it will be remains at the bottom. we can't able to find out which items are active.

Is there any function or logic to sort items in legend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported. You need to loop through all series and points and then update each series using [`series.update({ legendIndex: sortedIndex })`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update%28%29) function.

Comment: thanks pawel.. regarding this, how can i pointing the legendindex for each legend item?? when i click on any item inside legend, then how can i update the legend to sort the items? because i need to sort the items dynamically inside legend.

Comment: Here is example how to manage series indexes, see: http://jsfiddle.net/6neAd/1/ Of course you need to compare series values as you said, and you need to manage if series will be show or hide.